# Получение списка выделенных строк в datagridview C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Данные заношу в dataGridView из следующего списка: `public List<Fruit> Fruits = new List<Fruit>();`
Сам класс:

```
    public class Fruit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Calories { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public double Rating { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть кнопка на форме, когда пользователь выделяет одну или несколько строк и нажимает на removebutton, то  мы должны считывать индексы выделенных строк в список, а потом удалять из списка Fruits элементы по индексу.
Сама кнопка:

```
  private void removebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> mass = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select
            (
                 x => x.Index
            ).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < mass.Count; i++)
            {
                Fruits.RemoveAt(mass[i]);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Fruits;
        }
```

Здесь же при запуске получаем следующую картину: при выделении любого количества строк mass остается пустым, следовательно ничего не удаляется.

Comment: Предлагаю добавить столбец checkbox и в модель свойство `IsSelected`. Тогда при изменении данного свойства вы сможете получать все элементы у которых было изменено данное свойство. Также в заголовке столбца нажав на checkbox вы сможете в любой момент выделить или снять все элементы.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять тип у `Fruits` на `BindingList<Fruit>`, а эту строчку `dataGridView1.DataSource = Fruits` убрать.

Comment: Не получилось? [Вот](https://yadi.sk/d/EfyCPVKwLshBJg) нашел у себя старый демо-проект с использованием `BindingList`, писал его для одного из ответов на StackOverflow. Но сам ответ не могу найти, быть может автор удалил свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из опыта работы с формами и конкретно DevExpress'ом могу сказать следующее.

1. Вместо простого `List` во всех `DataGridView` нужно использовать `BindingList`
2. После того, как вы запрашиваете `SelectedItems` вам нужно просто выполнить их `Remove()` в `BindingList` на уровне бизнес-логики, что приведет к автоматическому обновлению таблицы

Конкретно внутреннюю механику работы `DataGridView` рассказать не могу, но простой `List` не вызывает обновление грида, в отличии от `BindingList`

```cs
public BindingList<Fruit> Fruits = new BindingList<Fruit>();
```

```cs
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    IEnumerable<object> selectedItems = dataGridView1.SelectedRows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select(x => x.DataBoundItem);

    foreach (object item in selectedItems)
    { 
        if (item is Fruit fruit) Fruits.Remove(fruit); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @aepot большое спасибо, в будущем буду стараться форматировать ответы так же.

Comment: Спасибо, очень сильно помогли!

Comment: _предоставляться слоем бизнес-логики через интерфейс_ Я вот это перепроверил, `BindingList<T>` не реализует `IBindingList<T>`, такого интерфейса просто нет, поэтому `DataGridView` нужно в `DataSource` скармливать сам `BindingList<T>`, а не интерфейс `IBindingList`. Либо я вас не правильно понял.

Comment: @aepot, нет, я плохо сформулировал ответ. Речь идет об архитектуре MVC, адаптированной для форм. View - форма со всеми событиями, Controller определяет, какие делегаты на какое событие подписывать, Model определяет слой бизнес-логики, на котором и будет храниться `BindingList<T>`. Инициализация проходила по принципу View-Controller-Model-Controller-View. После того, как модель подтягивала все необходимое из бизнеса, она спускала данные в контроллер, который назначал их в View.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за объяснение, просто увидел эту часть полезной и посмотрел на практике, не стоит ли оптимизировать объявление `BindingList`, и не смог этого сделать. Надеюсь вы не против, что я добавил код в ответ. :) Если вы видите, что его можно улучшить, отредактируйте ответ, я закончил со своими правками.

Comment: Удалил часть ответа, не соответствующуюю вопросу, вопросы архитектуры не нужны в этом ответе, пусть останутся в комментариях.